# Bootstrap - change the order of element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 divs both with col-md-6.

[image]

i want it to change to col-xs-12 for mobile

but the order should be:

[image]

using bootstrap, what should i do to make the box B on top of box A

Comment: With only using css?

Comment: using bootstrap

Comment: Did you try using the property "order" of flexbox ?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap V3 ar V4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try using "order" property of flexbox in CSS.**

Flex items are displayed in the same order as they appear in the source document by default. The order property can be used to change this ordering.

Sample code to help you understand this : https://jsfiddle.net/bhyqeq5x/

In the above JS fiddle , above 700px , it is rendered as A B (normal behaviour)but below 700px , I am changing the direction of flex box to column so that it appears one below the other and changing the order of A and B as per your requirement.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {  
   .container {    
     flex-direction : column;  
   }  
   .A {
     order : 2;   
   }  
   .B {
          order : 1;
    } 
}
```

Let me know in comments below if this doesnt help you.

Comment: woah, i didn't know there's something like this before. thanks ! upvoted

Comment: @KennethC : There are a lot of things that can be achieved using flexbox in  CSS. Try reading https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @KennethC : If this was helpful to you, can you please mark it as accepted answer to help others in future?

Comment: I have issues with safari tho. :(

Comment: What is the issue with it? Can you put a screenshot or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can order the elements using a flex container.

The outer div is set to "display: flex;" and the inside elements get given an order. By giving element B an order of 1, and element A an order 2. Element B will be placed before A even though A is first in the code.

Here's a sample bit of code I wrote;

```
#flex-container{
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

#a, #b{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#a{
  order: 2;
  background-color:#000;
}
#b{
  order: 1;
  background-color:#575757;
}
<div id="flex-container">
  <div id="a"></div>

  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

w3 schools also have a great demo of flex ordering in action here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_order

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Bootstrap V4`, simply use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` in the media query.

Or

If you are using  `Bootstrap V3` simply use `float: right;` in the media query for the `col-*` and place the `HTML` as given below

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">A</div>
```