# How to change position of divs using media queries

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'm trying to change the position of 2 divs on my page.
This is how it should look on [large screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkeY2.png)
I'm using bootstrap to fix the layout of the screen

```
d-flex justify-content-start
```

And this is how it should look on [medium and lower screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjvRi.png)
Thought of using this bootstrap class for the medium screens

```
d-flex flex-column-reverse
```

Notice the orders of divs 1 and 2.

Comment: Could you show the code that you're using? Or maybe a codepen so that we see what you have done?

Comment: You can find better ways here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611735/bootstrap-change-the-order-of-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611735/bootstrap-change-the-order-of-element)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'll check them out tomorrow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the custom bootstrap **order** classes and grid classes to achieve this. No need for media queries. Just specify `order-lg-1` for large screens on **DIV 1** and `order-md-2` so it will be ordered 2nd on medium screens. Likewise, on **DIV 2** use the class `order-lg-2` so it will be ordered 2nd on large screens but `order-md-1` so it will be ordered 1st on medium screens.

**HTML** could look something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 order-lg-1 order-md-2 customDiv">DIV 1</div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 order-lg-2 order-md-1 customDiv">DIV 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** could be something as simple as:

```
.customDiv {
  border: 5px solid black;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Link to codepen that shows this: https://codepen.io/andyreesecups-the-decoder/pen/mdbgEVY

Link about bootstrap grid classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Your div class names should be:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-9 col-12 order-lg-11">Div 2</div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-12 order-lg-1">Div 1</div>
</div>
```

Remember to be mobile first.

Edit: had them switched the wrong way.